# Getting the count of customers for each version, only including the highest version a customer has

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, opensearch

I have an aggregation to get the count of customers for each version:

```json
{
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "version.string.keyword",
        "order": {
          "_key": "desc"
        },
        "size": 50
      },
      "aggs": {
        "1": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "orgId.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The problem with this is that if a customer has two versions running at the same time, the customer will be included in both versions. What I need is for the customer to be included only in the highest version. For example, if I've got documents:

```json
{
    "orgId": "A",
    "version": {
        "string": "1.1",
        "major": 1,
        "minor": 1
    }
}
{
    "orgId": "A",
    "version": {
        "string": "1.2",
        "major": 1,
        "minor": 2
    }
}
{
    "orgId": "B",
    "version": {
        "string": "1.1",
        "major": 1,
        "minor": 2
    }
}
```

The response should be:

```json
[
    {
        "1": {
            "value": 1
        },
        "key": "1.1"
    },
    {
        "1": {
            "value": 1
        },
        "key": "1.2"
    }
]
```

instead of:

```json
[
    {
        "1": {
            "value": 2
        },
        "key": "1.1"
    },
    {
        "1": {
            "value": 1
        },
        "key": "1.2"
    }
]
```

I've tried this query which correctly returns highest version for each customer:

```json
{
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "orgId.keyword",
        "order": {
          "_key": "desc"
        },
        "size": 50
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sorted_version": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "version.major": {
                  "order": "desc"
                },
                "version.minor": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "version.string"
              ]
            },
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm kinda lost now on how to combine these two queries, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This results help you?

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_version_string": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "version.string.keyword",
        "order": {
          "_key": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_by_orgId": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "orgId.keyword",
            "order": {
              "_key": "desc"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response

```
 "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "1.2",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "group_by_orgId": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "A",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "1.1",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "group_by_orgId": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "B",
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "A",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, "A" should not show up in "1.1".